# Usage of type attribute in HTML5

Tags: html, forms

```
  <body>
    <form action="Welcome.html" method="get" id="user_id">
        <input type="submit" formmethod="post" value="post method submit"/> </br>
    <input type="submit" formtarget="_blank" value="opens in new window"/> </br>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above code , they have used type="submit" . Is this "submit" a predefined one or it can be anything. Can I also use type="pradeeba" (user defined attribute).

And second query is on value attribute. For certain tags i could find that value is mentioned whereas in certain places value is not metioned. Is value a mandatory attribut for every input type.

Pls help on the two queries.

Comment: "submit" a predefined one

Comment: You should post separate problems as separate questions, or at leasr write the question title so that it describes the question as a whole. Now the question title reflects the first question only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`submit` is a predefined type.

Per the W3C http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.html:

```
input type=text
input type=password
input type=checkbox
input type=radio
input type=button
input type=submit
input type=reset
input type=file
input type=hidden
input type=image
input type=datetime
input type=datetime-local
input type=date
input type=month
input type=time
input type=week
input type=number
input type=range
input type=email
input type=url
input type=search
input type=tel
input type=color
```

`type="pradeeba"` will render as a `type="text"` element in all browsers I'm aware of.

Comment: Thanks for answering the first query.Pls help on the second query

Comment: The cited reference is non-normative. You should cite either HTML5 CR or HTML 5.1 WD or WHATWG HTML (whichever you regard as closest to “HTML5 standard”).

Answer (score -2):

Value attribute specifies the initial value of the control. It is optional.

Comment: It is always optional, for radio buttons and checkboxes, too.